# Share calendar details request from manager's manager

Tags: email, france, events

My manager's manager just sent all his teams an email to ask us to open our Outlook calendars to him. Our Outlook calendar should only contain events relevant to our job, no personal life.

Opening a calendar means that he/she will be available to see the title of our events/meetings and their location.

Is this legal?

Context: France, the company is a multinational, our team is about 60 people worldwide

Update: By default, all the people in our big enterprise company are able to see the calendar availability of every other employee, but they cannot see the title and the location. They can only see that you are 'busy'

Comment: `Opening a calendar means that he/she will be available to see the title of our events/meetings and their location.` That is the intent - (why) is that a problem?

Comment: "Is this legal?" This sounds more like a question for https://law.stackexchange.com/ to me.

Comment: Who owns the email server?  Do we assume that this email is a WORK email address that the company provides?  The question greatly changes if I were asked to share my personal Microsoft account email calendar versus my employer account email.

Comment: Can you clarify why you think that any of this is a problem?

Comment: There is a lot of answer showing a miss understanding of the France Tag. People have issue understanding basic cultural difference. It's not legal, if you want it to be. Employer need your validation to check it. Most of the time it's done in a room where he doesn't not have access to the computer or able to read the screen and it's either broad cast or printed. With a worker representative in the room.

Comment: So the real question is why this question? Is that a genius question about french law? That will be quickly complexe cause of 'collection collective' and the contact. If you feel like your have an issue, Contact your worker representative or the closest one they will redirect you, and answer your question.

Comment: I don't know if a Calendar could be consider in the "Secret de la correspondance privée" from 2001 Nikon. Does any of those event were labelled as [private] or [perso]? Those cannot be read, if you are not there only a judge can all them to be read if there is enought doubt.

Comment: @Keeta, since 2001 in France it doesn't matter who own what. if it's labeled as Private. you will need a judge and enought proof. Expect if he rename C drive pas private.

Comment: @JMK I'd be more concerned that installing Outlook on your phone would have you agree with giving the company partial rights on the phone in order to use email. I've seen this happen if you connect a different email client on a phone with Exchange. I believe this is not always the case but if company has set it up, you basically have to agree for the company to [be able to wipe your phone remotely](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients/exchange-activesync/remote-wipe?view=exchserver-2019). That is supposed to be done if the phone is lost but...it doesn't sit well with me.

Comment: Do you believe management is not allowed to know what employees are working on? If no, why is this specific method of doing so a problem to you? If yes, how are they supposed to measure your performance and check your workload and where you may need help?

Comment: Let me understand this - the company; that owns and provides the calendar; is asking for you to change the permissions on it.  Seems to me like if you don't do it; the alternative is that the systems team make it a policy and have it done behind your back... like it or not.

Comment: @AmiralPatate in the cases where I've seen this, it wasn't a *requirement*. Somebody just thought it'd be convenient to get emails on his phone and tried to just connect. However, Exchange required giving over some level of access to the phone, after which the person just dropped the idea. My point was to notify about this possibility. That happened using a normal email app but connected to a Microsoft mail server, so I am fairly confident Outlook would probably do the same, if not more. I personally stay away from using personal gadgets for work.

Comment: @xdtTransform The question stated there should be no personal events in the calendar.

Comment: @xdtTransform Any reference to that? Sharing calendars is certainly not against any EU regulation (this seems analogous to email, where it's perfectly legal for the company to read your mail as long as they make it clear they'll do so and that you aren't allowed to use it for private correspondence). So while France might have much stronger privacy regulations than Germany or the rest of the EU this seems strange.

Comment: @xdtTransform Sure, the employer has to tell you that the email might be monitored and that you're not allowed to use it for private correspondence. Standard EU law. But there's nothing that forbids the employer from telling employees "this calendar can only be used for work related data" as done here. Or at least your links don't make any mention of this either. (There has to be a valid business case for this, but that should be trivial to show in this situation)

Comment: @xdtTransform If you get an official order to **not** store private data on a system (and there's a good business case for that) and you do, they might not be allowed to look at it, but they can certainly fire you for obeying a direct order. Just imagine if I could store my whole movie collection on my company's NAS and they could do nothing about it..

Comment: @xdtTransform Neither of those things matter. What matters is that you chose to continually ignore a direct business-related order from your manager without any good excuse. That's a fireable offense even in France.

Comment: Why would you expect to use your Outlook calendar on a work computer for personal items and NOT have it visible to the organization?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

> *Is this legal?*

If legality is the primary concern, this should be asked in [law stack exchange](https://law.stackexchange.com/).

However, if the question is more about the *practice*, opening up the calendar to other employees and managers is not unheard of and since you already understand that it's only for the company use, as long as it is visible to only company employees, I do not see a concern there.

Your manager (and manager's manager, and so forth) is responsible for managing your time, and having a look at your calendar is one of the easiest ways to do some of that work. If anyone is not using the calendar booking to *steal* time (useless meetings / unnecessary meeting bookings etc), there's nothing wrong in having an open calendar.

Personal example: In our team, we have calendars visible to whole team and manager (+1) and Business Unit head (+2) level.

Comment: I'd say it was commonplace rather than "not unheard of"!  I always look at others calendars when trying to find slots for meetings etc.  OP, any events which you set as 'Private' would be displayed only to you, anyone else looking at the calendar would just see "busy" or "private event"

Comment: @AdzzzUK I would not disagree, but to find a free slot, you need not have access to open calendar anyways. Just knowing free/busy would be enough, which is the default access level in outlook, IIRC.

Comment: yes, of course.  Outlook will display available time-slots when planning meetings.  My point was I find the request to view subordinates calendars as being relatively commonplace in a business environment.  My second point was merely to act as a "heads-up" for the OP in case they wanted to have certain stuff private.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Well, you might know a certain meeting could be bumped or cancelled in favor of your meeting. So knowing what the meetings are, when applicable, could be helpful.

Comment: @AzorAhai Right, I never said otherwise, it's just that to know the availability, you don't need the meeting subject to be known.

Comment: @SouravGhosh If Manager X comes around to the desk looking for your co-worker, it is useful to be able to see location and inform them if the meeting that just ended is in the current building, or on the other side of town.  Or, they might ask "is she in the meeting about QRZ at the moment?".  Any events whose location or title is private should be *marked* as "Private", so that only other attendees can see the calendar details.

Answer (score 22):

> Is this legal?

Why would it not be?

You just said it doesn't include anything personal and work related things only. If you're at work and clocked in/supposed to be working, your manager has every right to know where you are at all times never mind your managers manager.

They're paying you to do what they require. Managers need to manage their employees and resources in order to get a job done, how can they do that without knowing when you're free, what work you're doing and when you're doing it.

Answer (score 14):

Perfectly legal and widely used practice, at least in the UK - makes easier for managers to look after your time and schedule meetings. Also, find you in the big offices if there is need.

Comment: What? Outlook is perfectly capable in scheduling meetings without opening the calendar for the organizer. It just shows which slots are blocked, which is sufficient to schedule meetings.

Comment: @Simon the slots "blocked" might be "fake" or rather *irrelevant*, though. Not because the employee is deliberately faking it but, say, there is a recurring meeting that is slotted for 30 minutes but you know usually takes 5. Or perhaps there is a meeting that will be cancelled/postponed but hasn't yet (waiting for arrangements), so scheduling another over it is acceptable. Coversely, there might be a meeting that goes extra long, so booking another right after is undesirable. Without knowledge of the meeting, you can't separate which is which.

Comment: @VLAZ Or the meeting that a manager is trying to arrange is more important than an existing one, and the manager might elect to cancel/postpone the existing one (ideally not something that should happen _routinely_, but will be appropriate sometimes). Note the answer says "_makes [it] easier_" to schedule meetings; it doesn't claim it can't be done without the deeper access.

Comment: @TripeHound that, too. Basically, there are many reasons why a simple "busy" on the calendar might not be sufficient for planning a meeting alone. There is an entirely separate issue that somebody might be interested in just looking at what meetings there are. Perhaps they want to see when the next meeting for project A is, even if they aren't invited or don't plan on going. Or they might be interested in when the last one *was*.

Answer (score 6):

This is almost certainly legal unless you're in a company that needs to comply with certain data protection regulations and the calendars contain protected data.

As to whether or not it's a good idea, why might it *not* be a good idea? Companies vary in how open they are with information within the company, how well they need to secure certain kinds of information, and how they do that. Especially in smaller companies that are either not dealing with a lot of data whose exposure could cause significant loss, there may be no serious issue with everybody in the company being able to see everything everybody else's calendar. Even in larger companies, moving towards more openness is a trend, though it's arguable how popular it is. For example, one of the design goals of team communication tools like [Slack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slack_(software)) is to better expose conversations that had previously been hidden in e-mail, allowing someone not originally involved in an exchange to join a channel and see the full history of that exchange.

From your question it sounds as if you haven't really analyzed what information is in your calendars and what kind of problems could be caused by certain people seeing it. Problematic situations might include:

1. In a hospital, someone not allowed to access particular patient data being able to see that a certain doctor is meeting a certain patient. This would be an exposure of patient medical information, since you could guess things about the patient's medical conditions from that.
2. Someone not involved in the sales process being able to see that a salesperson is meeting with a certain company. It is often wise to keep quiet that a sale to a particular company is in progress lest competitors get wind of it and work to disrupt that sale.

So what information is in the calendars in question that poses some sort of risk if your manager's manager knows that information? This situation sounds to me as if it shouldn't be an issue at all, unless data protection regulations are involved. A manager well above you but still directly above you is usually considered trustworthy enough (except in very sensitive situations) that exposing to him what you're doing should not be an issue.

Opening your calendar to other employees at your level or below, or managers in a different part of the company, might be less wise. But even that (again, in the absence of data production regulation issues) is a business decision.

One thing you should do is inform your manager of this request, unless your manager's manager specifically requested you not do so. Your manager can raise the issue with his manager if he has any problem with this that needs to be worked out.

Answer (score 4):

> My manager's manager just sent all his teams an email to ask us to open our Outlook calendars to him.

This sounds like a perfectly reasonable and ordinary request. These are work events scheduled with company equipment and held on company time.

As a general rule, there is no reasonable expectation of privacy with your work computer if that's what you're concerned about.

> Our Outlook calendar should only contain events relevant to our job, no personal life.

It's completely reasonable to expect that you'll use company-issued equipment primarily for business purposes.

> Opening a calendar means that he/she will be available to see the title of our events/meetings and their location. Is that legal?

Of course it is. Why would it be illegal for your boss's boss to know the title and location of your work meetings?

Answer (score 3):

Local laws will obviously vary, but I know in the US, generally any information and messages related to work-based email or calendaring is the property of the employer, and there's no particular requirement that certain managers, HR, or other privileged staff need even tell you that they are going to access that material before doing so.

With this in mind, I think the only serious question here is if your manager's manager is in a role appropriate to be accessing that information, or if they have the authority to make the request they've made.

Barring that, or some provision in the GDPR or something, I don't really see how the request is even a major problem. In this day and age there's no reason to be using your work email/calendar system for your personal appointments, though it's totally reasonable to block out time for lunch or other events where you will genuinely be out of the office during work time. Whatever the end goal, it is probably within their rights to view and analyze this information, and I would be surprised if they had not already been doing so if they are that interested in it.

Answer (score 0):

With the others on the topic of "is it legal" - a lawyer would know better, but yes it likely is.
With the others on whether this is something to worry about as well.  This may have been a request but I can't imagine they even need your permission, IT staff would be able to change your settings or make events visible to management anyways.

If you are intending to hide something from your managers, I would suggest using services not directly controlled by your employer.  A personal Google, Apple, Microsoft account, specific apps, etc.

Answer (score 0):

> Opening a calendar means that he/she will be available to see the title of our events/meetings and their location.

The only reasons this could be a problem are :

- An event or meeting is taking place which you are involved in and *explicitly* should not be known by your manager's manager.  For example a meeting with HR about them.
- There are meetings your immediate boss or HR are entitled to know but which are considered private.  Perhaps a medical appointment or some confidential reason.

I would suggest checking company policy on this with HR.  It may be that this manager is trying to find out e.g. who was talking to HR "behind their back" or something like that.  It won't do any harm to check if they're allowed to be doing this (or possibly even not supposed to do it for some policy reason).

Be discrete checking this.

> Update: By default, all the people in our big enterprise company are able to see the calendar availability of every other employee, but they cannot see the title and the location. They can only see that you are 'busy'

It's not always appropriate for any manager above you to be able to see *exactly* who you are meeting for reasons I have explained.  I personally find it a little odd that a manager would do this, not least because it bypasses your line manager, who you actually report to.  It need not be sinister, but it's rather pointless having layers of management if people are going to e.g. micro-manage multiple layers.

> Our Outlook calendar should only contain events relevant to our job, no personal life.

Someone has already commented that this is an ideal which in practical terms can be broken without trying to deliberately by all the automation smart phone and tablet have.  Rules like this are often made by people who have no idea how modern technology works, or are inherited from a time when the technology was quite different.

In practical terms if you need to flag you are unavailable because you have to e.g. leave by a certain time on a particular day, then it's quite useful to have that unavailability flagged in a work calendar so people don't try and stick a meeting (or whatever) in that slot.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a little controversial, but the biggest problem I see is the "no private information" issue.  Some things are personal, but affect work time, and an overly strict interpretation of this is problematic.

- Those who have arranged  working hours to meet childcare for example may need private stuff in there. e.g. 2 nights a week I'm out of the door at 17:00, no exceptions unless planned in advance.  No I can't squeeze in a 15 minute meeting - I'll miss my train and be 1/2 hour late for pickup.
- Medical and other critical personal appointments may lead to unusual break times, all fully approved at a local level and within policy, but higher-ups need to respect this.

I would say this is relevant to work, so put it in, but I've met managers who would say that's using the work calendar to plan your personal life - and they tend to be the same managers who want immediate access to every detail of your calendar.

Comment: Is anything stopping employees from just creating "Busy" events in their calendar (or even "Medical leave" or whatever)? It seems there's a lot of middle ground between omitting it entirely and having an event saying "Appointment with Doctor X to look at my Y".

Comment: @Dukeling IME  setting a title of "busy", "leave promptly", or even "personal" would satisfy most people, but the exceptions tend to be the same people who want full visibility in the first place

Comment: If they absolutely strictly don't allow anything personal on the calendar, then fine, that's their right. But they will just have to deal with the fact that all participants will need to actively decline meeting invites scheduled for times when they won't be there for a personal reason